# faster alternatives to .apply() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, yfinance, pandas-apply

I am trying to speed up the process of applying a custom function to columns in a data frame. I have found that this:

```
b = b.apply(lambda x: 'not_ticker' if x is None else x)
b = b.apply(lambda x: x if x=='not_ticker' else x if isTICKER(x) else 'not_ticker')
```

is much faster than this:

```
b = b.apply(lambda x: x if isTICKER(x) else 'not_ticker')
```

where:

```
b
Out[25]: 
0     None
1     None
2     None
3     None
4     None
5     None
6     None
7     None
8     SOLD
9     None
10    NVAX
11      GM
12    None
13    None
Name: tickers_body_3, dtype: object
```

my function isTICKER() returns True if the string passed to it is a valid stock

```
def isTICKER(ticker_in):
    """
    isTICKER(ticker)
    Arguments:
       ticker_in(str): string to be verified as ticker

    Returns:
        isticker(boolean): positive if item is a valid ticker in yfinance database
    """
    import yfinance as yf
    if ticker_in is not None:
        if len(ticker_in)>2:
            ticker = yf.Ticker(str(ticker_in))
            info = None
            if ticker.info['regularMarketPrice'] is None:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Unfortunately, this is still very slow and needs to run on a much larger data set than the example given.
The final output should look like this:

```
b = b.apply(lambda x: 'not_ticker' if x is None else x)
b = b.apply(lambda x: x if x=='not_ticker' else x if isTICKER(x) else 'not_ticker')
print(b)
0     not_ticker
1     not_ticker
2     not_ticker
3     not_ticker
4     not_ticker
5     not_ticker
6     not_ticker
7     not_ticker
8     not_ticker
9     not_ticker
10          NVAX
11    not_ticker
12    not_ticker
13    not_ticker
Name: tickers_body_3, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of calling to `IsTICKER` for each value separately, you can call it only once per unique value, and save results as dictionary:

```
dict_res = {x: isTICKER(x) for x in np.unique(b.values)}`
```

This line creates a mapping between each **unique** value to the result of your function. Then, all you need is to replace the values according to your dictionary. This can be done easily with `.map` function:

`b = b.map(dict_res)`

The are two "hacks" here to accelerate performance, comparing to your code:

1. Calling to your custom function (which might be slow) only on the unique values instead of the whole series. Useful if you have values that repeated often in your series.
2. Using `.map` instead of `.apply`